# Using ng2engine in Python

Tags: python, angularjs, express, angular-fullstack, isomorphic-javascript

I built an Angular 2 Universal app. I was able to make it work using, node-express and ng2engine. But, I have a situation where I need to use Python instead of node express. So, is there any way to do the same thing using Python instead of node-express? Can we use ng2engine in Python? or is there is any way to handle this in python so that the Angular 2 components gets rendered?